# Единая авторизация в apex и php

Tags: php, сессия, auth, oracle-apex

Доброго времени суток, коллеги!

Возникла такая проблема. Есть приложение написанное на apex и отдельный модуль на php. Необходимо, что бы при переходе из приложения apex к php-модулю - не требовалась повторная авторизация.

Даже не знаю каким образом возможно в php использовать сессию apex... Переход к модулю происходит по ссылке. При авторизации apex используется стандартная функция `wwv_flow_custom_auth_std.login`

Может кто сталкивался?

Comment: можно просто сессию в куках хранить, и по ключу получать значения от туда. Либо создавать сессию для php с определёным ключом в apex а потом передовать этот ключ как id сессии. Т.е. просто скопировать сесcию

Comment: SSO? : https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%85%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0

Comment: Проект большой очень. И разрабатывали его сторонние разработчики. На сессии много где что завязано (Это я про сторону apex'a). Безболезненно хотелось бы "присобачить" свой модуль.